# Jenkins slave on windows doesn't show logs

Tags: java, powershell, jenkins

I have Jenkins master on Ubuntu host in docker containers, connected to it is a windows slave that i run Jenkins on it using a PowerShell script that launch the agent:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://XX.XX.XX..../jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret XXX... -workDir "/jenkins"
```

we start the launch agent script using this script that creates the job:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:30
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $trigger -FilePath start_agent.ps1 -Name MyJob
```

my issues is:

1. when i go to the master UI and go to the slave node - i press on "logs" but it doesn't show anything, it just loads forever with 3 dots loading
2. I tried to redirect logs using `*>&1 > output.txt` at the end of the `java -jar` command but it doesn't work. and I haven't found any java jar argument that works in redirecting the output have tried -XX file path , couldn't find the Log4j file

i have a directory in the windows jenkins path named "remoting" and it has logs but it only have restart logs and not live logs\error logs and i need it.

Thanks.

Comment: This works for me to redirect Java output to a file: `java @javaArgs *>&1 | ForEach-Object { "$_" } | Tee-Object "$PSScriptRoot\AgentLog.txt" -Append`. I don't think the `ForEach-Object` and `Tee-Object` commands are really necessary, it really should work like `java ... *>&1 > output.txt` as well. Did you literally include the double quotation marks? These must be omitted!

Comment: My `$javaArgs` basically contains the same parameters as in your sample, except that I'm passing only absolute paths for `-jar` and `-workDir`.

Comment: @zett42 If i run the start-agent.ps with the output `*>&1 > output.txt` it works but if the other ps script of creating the job running the script of start-agent the redirect doesn't work, i think it something to do with that but i dont understand what

Comment: Could you try to create a simple example that I can copy-paste to reproduce the issue?

Comment: create a ps script that creates a job: `$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:30
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $trigger -FilePath start_agent.ps1 -Name MyJob
`  and create a java command in the start_agent.ps1 with output redirect in the end, if the create job is runing the script no redirect file is created, this specific start-agent is a jenkins jave command so i cannot give you the full script as it wont work for you

Comment: The job is triggerd to be created after windows vm restart

Comment: Sorry, can't even get the job to run successfully this way. Does it work with a manually created job? Make sure to use absolute path for the log file, e. g. `$PSScriptRoot\AgentLog.txt`.